# C++: How to pass object to function as templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want to write a class such that I can define its template type in the class declaration (ie `class AChar : public A<char>`), and then be able to pass derived classes into functions which accept the parent class, as I would with a non-templated parent class. Is there a way to do this or some way to achieve the same effect?

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A
{
  T value;
  A(T t) : value(t) {};
  virtual void say() const = 0;
};

struct AChar : public A<char>
{
  AChar(char c) : A(c) {};
  void say() const
  {
    std::cout << "A char: " << this->value << std::endl;
  }
};

struct ABool : public A<bool>
{
  ABool(bool b) : A(b) {};
  void say() const
  {
    std::cout << "A bool: " << this->value << std::endl;
  }
};

void makeSay(A a)
{
  a.say();
}

int main()
{
  AChar aChar('g');
  ABool aBool(true);

  makeSay(aChar); // A char: g
  makeSay(aBool); // A bool: 1
}
```

I want to write a class for the binary representation of a data type. For this, I have a class DataType which is extended by various data type classes (eg IntType, BoolType, ShortType, etc) as posted below. I want to be able to pass these derived classes into a function which can handle any of those types on a binary level. I've posted header files below:

datatype.h

```
#ifndef _DATATYPE_H_
#define _DATATYPE_H_

#include <cstddef>

template<class T>
class DataType
{
public:
  std::size_t sizeOf() const;
  virtual void toBytes(const T&, char*) const = 0;
  virtual T fromBytes(char*) const = 0;
  virtual T zero() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

bytetype.h

```
#ifndef _BYTETYPE_H_
#define _BYTETYPE_H_

#include "numerictype.h"

class ByteType : public NumericType<char>
{
public:
  ByteType();
  void toBytes(char, char[1]) const;
  char fromBytes(char[1]) const;
  char zero() const;
};

#endif
```

chartype.h

```
#ifndef _CHARTYPE_H_
#define _CHARTYPE_H_

#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include "datatype.h"

class CharType : public DataType<std::string>
{
  std::size_t length;
public:
  static const char PADDING = ' ';

  CharType();
  CharType(size_t);
  std::size_t getLength() const;
  std::size_t sizeOf() const;
  void toBytes(const std::string&, char*) const;
  std::string fromBytes(char*) const;
  std::string zero() const;
};

#endif
```

example use

```
void writeToFile(DataType d)
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  CharType c(1);
  ByteType b;

  writeToFile(c);
  writeToFile(b);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have posted how. Why do you ask? The makeSay function will misbehave though.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe added header files from my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the base class is templated, the function you want to pass multiple derived types to must either:

1. itself be templated, in order to accept a base class (which you must pass by reference or pointer to avoid [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/)).

   ```
   template<class T>
   void makeSay(const A<T> &a)
   {
       a.say();
   }
   ```

   ```
   template<class T>
   void writeToFile(const DataType<T> &d)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. be overloaded for each specific derived type (which kind of defeats the purpose of using templates):

   ```
   void makeSay(const AChar &a)
   { 
       a.say();
   }

   void makeSay(const ABool &a)
   { 
       a.say();
   }
   ```

   ```
   void writeToFile(const ByteType &t)
   {
       // ...
   }

   void writeToFile(const CharType &t)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!!! I was worried that in doing something such as your first code snippet I would have to invoke it like `makeSay<char>(aChar)`

Comment: @terpak in this example, the template parameter can be deduced by the compiler